# password recovery for drupal

Tags: drupal, passwords, recovery

i forgot my **drupal user id and password**. Is there any way to recover it

Comment: This would be better suited for superuser

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`http://example.com/<path-to-drupal>/user/password` should bring you to a page where you can request a reset/new-password.

**Edit**:
The above path applies if you have '*clean URLs*' enabled, if not use `http://example.com/<path-to-drupal>/?q=user/password`

Answer (score 4):

This solution is valid for Drupal 5 or 6 but not for Drupal 7. This version does not use a standard hashed password. You can get your encoded password running the following command:

```
php /path_to_drupal_files/scripts/password-hash.sh your_password
```

Then you can see your password hash. This is the string that you should use in the database to update the admin password. You can use the following SQL query to update the Drupal database.

```
UPDATE users SET pass='YOUR_PASSWORD_HASH' where uid=1;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have access to the email (or want to bulk-update the passwords) you can update the database with a query like:

UPDATE users SET pass = md5('NEWPASSWORD') WHERE name = 'admin'

Comment: Don't forget to put the drupal prefeix before the table name.

Comment: Does anybody know how to do lyricnz's trick in D7 ? It looks like 7.x got a more tricky pass storage scheme.